# Insert data into Google Spreadsheet using Apache NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

How can I insert data into Google Spreadsheet using Apache NIFI? The only possible solution I can conceive right now is creating a python script and use Google Sheet API client in order to post data to Google Sheet.

But I'm looking for simpler ways to do that. It would be nice to have no or few dependencies. I tried the PostHTTP processor but could not authorize my requests on Google Sheet API servers. The GCPCrendentialsControllerService could be handy to authenticate requests, but I was not able to use that with PostHTTP processor.

I thought it would be a very common use case, but found nobody else trying to use Nifi to write on a google sheet. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably because most Java developers use the [Google spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java).

Comment: You could use executegroovyscript with code to write spreadsheet.

Comment: Not sure why you thought this would be a common use case, it's very niche - either way, it should still be possible using HTTP processors, though probably more complex than just using the API clients. The Sheets API will require OAuth2 tokens to work with private sheets, and Pierre did a write up about using OAuth2 here https://pierrevillard.com/2017/01/31/nifi-and-oauth-2-0-to-request-wordpress-api/comment-page-1/ - that should point you in the right direction to auth your requests

Answer (score 0):

In case that your NIFI is running in an environment that has access to your Google Drive you can use NIFI to save your data as CSV files. Otherwise, you can use NIFI to write the data as CSV file to a server that provides http/https access.

In both cases, you then use [ImportData](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335) in Google Sheets, providing it the required url.

Please note that this solution won't fit if you need real-time / high-speed processing. I use it for periodic reports from various sources etc.